# Auto-approve synonyms suggested by diamond moderators

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms

Recall that anyone can propose tag synonyms at `/tags/<tagname>/synonyms`, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-synonyms/synonyms). If a non-diamond user suggests the synonym, the synonym will require either voting by users with high score in that tag or diamond approval before the synonym goes into effect.

Curiously, even synonyms suggested by a diamond moderator at `/tags/<tagname>/synonyms` go into the approval queue.

> [image]

As a diamond moderator, I can then approve the synonym by clicking the "approve" link. But this is an extra step that doesn't seem to serve any clear purpose. As such, I would like to request that synonyms suggested by diamond moderators at `/tags/<tagname>/synonyms` be auto-approved.

(Yes, I know I can have my synonyms go into effect immediately by using the interface at `/admin/create-tag-synonym` instead. But I find this interface somewhat less friendly and prefer not to use it.)